# Reference a table of values to automatically output a sum using a compound IF statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a reference table that looks something like:
__ A______ | B____| C____| D____
1| Job Type | Hours | Fee 1 | Fee 2
2| Review_ | _2___ | $10__ | $15
3| Review_ | _4___ | $15__ | $15
4| Test____ | _2___ | $20__ | $10
5| Test____ | _4___ | $30__ | $10
6| Repair__ | _8___ | $60__ | $15
7| Repair__ | _16__ | $100_ | $20

I would like to be able to create price sheets by entering a job type and a number of hours, and have Excel automatically add up the appropriate amounts from columns C and D. For example, if I select "Review" and "4" for the hours, it would return $30.00, if I select "Test" and "4" for the hours it would return $40.

The following formula in an existing template:
`=SUM(IF(X1=(A2:A7),IF(X2=(B2:B7),(C2:C7)+(D2:D7),0),0))`
works, but if I highlight the cell with this formula and push "Enter" I get #VALUE and if I copy the formula to another worksheet it always returns 0. I feel like a VLOOKUP is probably needed but not sure how to implement it into a compound IF formula within a SUM.

Comment: Check out the `=SUMIF()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add two SUMIFS:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,X1,B:B,X2),SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,X1,B:B,X2))
```

Comment: Wouldn't this require me to add another layer of "IF" statements for each Job Type? In the actual build there are already 10 job types. Plus, if we add new job types in the future I would like to be able to just add to them into the reference table then increase the range checked by the formula.

Also, what does the "4" at the end of each SUMIFS statement do?

Comment: I've just realized the "4" in your formula is a reference to the number of hours in my example question. The problem is that I want to be able to enter the number of hours and job type into a separate worksheet with a "clean" appearance that can be presented to customers.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I am now getting the expected values based on the inputs!!!!